# VBA excel code to insert an entire row below matching a variable number of matching values

Tags: excel, vba, matching

I am a novice at writing vba code and would appreciate some guidance and help writing a basic macro. I am sorting data by three headings, and then separating the data by insering a blank row for matching values in column "B", starting with row B2 and ending at the last row. The pairs are of a variable quantity i.e. may be none, one, two or three matching values, but I just want to group them and insert a single row beneath the last matching value. Can someone help me please?

```
'Sub BetterFilter()
Dim CDpos As Worksheet
Set CDpos = Worksheets("CD positions with red bars")
AutoFilter = False
FilterMode = False
'the headers are from "A1:CT1"
Range("A1:CT2").Select
CDpos.AutoFilter.Sort. _
SortFields.Clear
CDpos.AutoFilter.Sort. _
'B2 is the first range i want to filter etc'
SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B2").End(xlDown), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
CDpos.AutoFilter.Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("M2:M2").End(xlDown), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
CDpos.AutoFilter.Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("CE2:CE2").End(xlDown), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With CDpos.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

'this is where i have problems and i want to bunch all my matched values in row B and insert a row below the last match value for each grouping' 
    For i = 1 To 2
    If Range("B2" & i).Value = Range("B2" & i + 1).Value Then
    Range(B2, & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert

End If
Next
End With
End Sub'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with something like:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Address)
'loop from B1 to the last used cell in column B
    If cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value2 <> cell.Value2 And cell.Offset(-1, 0) <> vbNullString Then cell.EntireRow.Insert
    'if the cell above is different and not null then it adds a row above
Next cell
```

and change "B2" to whatever your first use cell is.

Comment: Fantastic, this has worked a treat. Thank you very much